# Using spaces in env vars during Apache startup

Tags: apache, bash, shell, env

I want to pass an environment variable with a space in it to apache.
Apache uses env to start itself so in effect I have to make some thing like this work

```
export MYCMD=" env -i FOO=123\ 456"
$MYCMD
```

The result is

```
env: 456: No such file or directory
```

Looking at the strace output I see this

```
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "-i", "FOO=123\\", "456"], [/* 41 vars */]) = 0
```

as you can see the env utility has split up my FOO variable into two other variables because of the space.
I have tried all manner of options to try and maintain the space after env has digested the command but so far no luck.

You can try this on its own

```
env -i FOO=123\ 456 

FOO=123 456
```

All is well

```
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "-i", "FOO=123 456"],
```

The problem occurs when you place the command into another environment variable

Since this is what the Apache start up code does I am somewhat stuck with having to find a solution to this puzzle.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify the test, case first set up the env var like this      export MYCMD=" env -i FOO=123\ 456"  then just run $MYCMD

Comment: You can edit your original post if you have additional information to include.

Comment: In your "all is well" case, the third array element is `"FOO=123 456"`. I don't think the `execve`, when executed, will assign `123 456` to `FOO`. If you type `FOO=123 456` at the shell prompt, you would get `bash: 456: command not found...`.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding what you want, but you can try using an array instead of a simple variable.

```
export MYCMD=( env -i "FOO=123 456" )
"${MYCMD[@]}"
```

I suspect that's a little too simple for you, as "exporting" an array doesn't really work. I think `bash` does a little sleight-of-hand to make "exported" arrays visible to subshells, but strictly speaking an environment variable is simply a named string without any other type of structure.

How is `MYCMD` being used, exactly? Which file do you place it in? Changes to the environment persist, so if you were to set `FOO="123 456"` in the environment of the command that starts Apache, Apache would inherit `FOO` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would seem to be that the second level of quoting (the backslash in your eample) is not evaluated by a shell.

Is there a chance you can invoke your command like

```
eval "$MYCMD"
```

instead?